# How to load data parallelly in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**At first I will describe my application background**:

There are about 500,000 videos saved as avi files in my disk and i will use them as training samples. To use them we can load them simultaneously into the memory and then feed each batch into the model for trianing, which is the easiest way. However my memory is **NOT** big enough for the whole loading. Therefore i need to load the video data batchly. But you know, decode a batch(take 64 here) of video might cost a lot of time and if you do that serially, we will waste a lot of time in the data loading part instead of computing. Thus i want to batchly load the data parallelly, in fact, just like   the API `fit_generator` in keras. I wonder if there is a existing way to do that in TensorFlow.

Thanks for any suggestion:)

**PS:** i used to implement the idea by the `theading` package in Python, for more, visit here https://github.com/FesianXu/Parallel-DataLoader-in-TensorFlow

of course it is just a toy code and too ad hoc. I wanna a more general solution just like `fit_generator` in Keras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator):

> Creates a Dataset whose elements are generated by generator.
>
> The generator argument must be a callable object that returns an
>   object that support the iter() protocol (e.g. a generator function).
>   The elements generated by generator must be compatible with the given
>   output_types and (optional) output_shapes arguments.

This example shows how to easily parallelize the generator using [`tf.data.Dataset.map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) with the `num_parallel_calls` parameter: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14448#issuecomment-349240274

More info: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#parallelizing_data_extraction

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow has the Dataset API for this sort of thing.

See the tutorial and API documentation:

- [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets)
- [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)